# Vaadin + Spring = getting a nullpointer exception

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, vaadin

I'm using Vaadin to create a frontend side of my application. I'm trying to communicate through my ApiController to my backend so I can get my data from the database.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class ApiController {
    @Autowired
    private ApiClient apiClient;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "getDoctors")
    public void getAllDoctors() {
        List<DoctorDto> doctorsList = apiClient.getDoctors();
        doctorsList.forEach(doctorDto -> System.out.println(doctorDto.getName() + " " + doctorDto.getRating()));
    }
}
```

As of now I have only a main page with few tabs, one of which is where I want to list all doctors that are in the database.

MainView:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component // <--- I already have an import regarding Vaddin's components
@Route("test")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private DoctorsPage doctorsPage = new DoctorsPage(this);
    private Tab doctorsTab = new Tab("Our doctors");

    public MainView() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

and DoctorsPage:

```
@Component
public class DoctorsPage extends VerticalLayout {
    @Autowired
    private ApiClient apiClient;  // <---- not autowiring
    private MainView mainView;

    public DoctorsPage(MainView mainView) {
        this.mainView = mainView;
        List<DoctorDto> list = apiClient.getDoctors();
    }
}
```

Funny fact, if I try to use a browser and paste my endpoint for getting the list of doctors this code

```
doctorsList.forEach(doctorDto -> System.out.println(doctorDto.getName() + " " + doctorDto.getRating()));
```

works perfectly. But even when I'm trying to autowire my ApiClient in MainView class I'm still getting a null exception.

There are logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'doctorsPage' defined in file [C:\Users\x\IdeaProjects\medical-clinic-frontend\build\classes\java\main\com\x\medicalclinicfrontend\gui\DoctorsPage.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainView' defined in file [C:\Users\x\IdeaProjects\medical-clinic-frontend\build\classes\java\main\com\x\medicalclinicfrontend\gui\MainView.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.x.medicalclinicfrontend.gui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at com.x.medicalclinicfrontend.MedicalClinicFrontendApplication.main(MedicalClinicFrontendApplication.java:10) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mainView' defined in file [C:\Users\x\IdeaProjects\medical-clinic-frontend\build\classes\java\main\com\x\medicalclinicfrontend\gui\MainView.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.x.medicalclinicfrontend.gui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.x.medicalclinicfrontend.gui.MainView]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:213) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.x.medicalclinicfrontend.gui.MainView.<init>(MainView.java:38) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Heads up on the scope of DoctorPage - it defaults to singleon with Spring.  Most likely you want at least UI scope.

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring does not work inside instances that are created using the `new` keyword. Your `DoctorsPage` must instead be `@Autowired` to allow Spring to create an instance of the  instance, so that Spring can inject beans into its fields.

I also see that you have to use a fully qualified name for the `@Component` annotation in of of your classes. You can avoid this by instead using the `@SpringComponent` alias that is defined by Vaadin's Spring integration.

Comment: yes, but even when I make an autowired field with ApiClient the debugger still shows that it's a null. Not making a new instance of DoctorsPage also doesn't work, since it gives me a null, although a different 'caused by'

Comment: @yomi If you try things out, that don't work, please edit your question and add the new insights.

Comment: Also it should be noted that field autowiring is performed after constructor, so autowired fields are null in constructor. You can autowire ApiClient as constructor parameter instead of field.

Answer (score 1):

Yomi,

If you're getting Spring to create your DoctorsPage, add another method with the @PostConstruct annotation and initialise the component in there.

```
@Component
public class DoctorsPage extends VerticalLayout {
    @Autowired
    private ApiClient apiClient;  
    private MainView mainView;

    public DoctorsPage(MainView mainView) { }

    @PostConstruct                               // <---- like this
    puvlic void init() {
        this.mainView = mainView;
        List<DoctorDto> list = apiClient.getDoctors();
    }
}
```

Or as @Tatu Lund says, auto wire apiClient in the constructor.

Stuart.

Answer (score 1):

**Credit for the answer goes to @Tatu Lund and @Stainless Steel Rat**

So it's like you guys said, it should be autowired in a constructor:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Component
@Route("test")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private DoctorsPage doctorsPage;

    @Autowired
    public MainView (DoctorsPage doctorsPage) {
        this.doctorsPage = doctorsPage;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class DoctorsPage extends VerticalLayout {
    private ApiClient apiClient;

    @Autowired
    public DoctorsPage(ApiClient apiClient) {
        this.apiClient = apiClient;
    }
}
```

I couldn't immediately confirm the solution since I have much going on within these two classes and it took me a bit to make it work but that's what matters, it works : D

Thanks again guys **@Tatu Lund** and **@Stainless Steel Rat** and others as well.